# Difference between SVR and other simple regression models

Tags: machine-learning, regression, svm

Can someone help me to understand that what's the main difference between Support vector regression technique and other simple regression models.
Thanks

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `computer-vision` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support vector regression finds a linear function representing the data within a margin (epsilon) of error. That is, most of the points can be found inside that margin, as you can see on the figure below (from  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Support-vector-regression-SVR-Illustration-of-an-SVR-regression-function-represented_fig1_248396465):

[image: SVR]

It means that SVR is more robust to outliers than most other regression methods, since it does not care much about the data outside the margin

Comment: It is not exactly that. In SVR points within epsilon do not produce an error, points outside do give an error. The idea is to minimise the loss so the method will try to find the line that keeps as many points as possible within epsilon. But outliers will still affect.